# Get permutations of subset of row entries for all rows in sqlserver table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have a table like this:

```
idx  | a1 | a2 | a3 | b1 | c1
-----------------------------
idx1, a11, a12, a13, b11, c11
idx2, a21, a22, a23, b21, c21
idx3, a31, a32, a33, b31, c31
idx4, a41, a42, a43, b41, c41
```

and I would like to add rows to the table that have permutations of the subset of columns (a1, a2, a3) of the existing rows. Eg. row1 would contribute additional rows like:

```
idx  | a1 | a2 | a3 | b1 | c1
-----------------------------
idx1, a11, a12, a13, b11, c11
idx1, a11, a13, a12, b11, c11
idx1, a12, a11, a13, b11, c11
idx1, a12, a13, a11, b11, c11
idx1, a13, a11, a12, b11, c11
idx1, a13, a12, a11, b11, c11
and so on for the other original rows...
```

Is how would I do this in sqlserver? Thanks

Comment: pretty sure you are going to need to use cross apply here, though i'm baffled as to why you want this.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but you'll probably want to use a self-join https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_self.asp.  EDIT: cross apply seems actually very appropriate

Comment: any of those work for you @reedv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a cross-join method.

```
declare @table table (indx varchar(4), a1 varchar(3), a2 varchar(3), a3 varchar(3), b1 varchar(3), c1 varchar(3))
insert into @table
values
('idx1','a11','a12','a13','b11','c11'),
('idx2','a21','a22','a23','b21','c21')

;with cte as(
    select indx, a1
    from @table
    union
    select indx, a2
    from @table
    union 
    select indx, a3
    from @table)

select distinct
    c1.indx
    ,c1.a1
    ,c2.a1 as a2
    ,c3.a1 as a3
    ,t.b1
    ,t.c1
from cte c1
    cross join cte c2
    cross join cte c3
    left join @table t on t.indx = c1.indx
where 
    c1.indx = c2.indx  
    and c3.indx = c1.indx
    and c1.a1 <> c2.a1
    and c1.a1 <> c3.a1
    and c2.a1 <> c3.a1
order by
    c1.indx
    ,c1.a1
    ,c2.a1
    ,c3.a1
```

**RETURNS**

```
+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| indx | a1  | a2  | a3  | b1  | c1  |
+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| idx1 | a11 | a12 | a13 | b11 | c11 |
| idx1 | a11 | a13 | a12 | b11 | c11 |
| idx1 | a12 | a11 | a13 | b11 | c11 |
| idx1 | a12 | a13 | a11 | b11 | c11 |
| idx1 | a13 | a11 | a12 | b11 | c11 |
| idx1 | a13 | a12 | a11 | b11 | c11 |
| idx2 | a21 | a22 | a23 | b21 | c21 |
| idx2 | a21 | a23 | a22 | b21 | c21 |
| idx2 | a22 | a21 | a23 | b21 | c21 |
| idx2 | a22 | a23 | a21 | b21 | c21 |
| idx2 | a23 | a21 | a22 | b21 | c21 |
| idx2 | a23 | a22 | a21 | b21 | c21 |
+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

Permutations, 5! combinations for every idx provided all values in the source row are different.

```
declare @t table(
    idx  varchar(10)
    , a1 varchar(10)
    , a2 varchar(10)
    , a3 varchar(10)
    , b1 varchar(10)
    , c1 varchar(10)
    );
insert @t 
values
 ('idx1','a11','a12','a13','b11','c11')
,('idx2','a21','a22','a23','b21','c21')
,('idx3','a31','a32','a33','b31','c31')
,('idx4','a41','a42','a43','b41','c41');

with pvt as (
    select idx,m 
    from @t
    cross apply ( 
         values(a1),(a2),(a3),(b1),(c1)
         ) vals(m)
)

select t1.idx, t1.m, t2.m, t3.m, t4.m, t5.m
from pvt t1
join pvt t2 on t1.idx=t2.idx and t2.m not in (t1.m)
join pvt t3 on t1.idx=t3.idx and t3.m not in (t1.m, t2.m)
join pvt t4 on t1.idx=t4.idx and t4.m not in (t1.m, t2.m, t3.m)
join pvt t5 on t1.idx=t5.idx and t5.m not in (t1.m, t2.m, t3.m, t4.m)
order by t1.idx, t1.m, t2.m, t3.m, t4.m, t5.m;
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried something like below? Your question is pretty vague regarding the uniqueness and the content of the a1, a2, a3 columns.

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT Idx, b1, c1, a1 AS a
  UNION
  SELECT Idx, b1, c1, a2 AS a
  UNION
  SELECT Idx, b1, c1, a3 AS a
)
SELECT cte1.Idx, cte1.b1, cte1.c1, cte1.a AS a1, cte2.a AS a2, cte3.a AS a3
FROM cte AS cte1
  JOIN cte AS cte2 ON cte1.Idx = cte2.Idx AND cte1.b1 = cte2.b1 AND cte1.c1 = cte2.c1
  JOIN cte AS cte3 ON cte1.Idx = cte3.Idx AND cte1.b1 = cte3.b1 AND cte1.c1 = cte3.c1
```